# Difference between variants and classification

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

What is the difference between a Variant and a Classification System?

I don't really understand why is there an `ApparelSizeVariantProduct` in the `*-items.xml` file only for a size variation. Isn't it easier to create a classification for a category that holds a "size" feature instead of creating a new type ?  What is the purpose of these "variants" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are sell and price strategy. For example in fashion, you need to manage stocks by **size**, but price managed by base product model. Some companies also manage price by color variant. So you need another variant for color.
**Example:** BaseProduct > ColorVariant > SizeVariant

You cannot manage price or stock with classification. Also there is another concept exists: attributes.

These functionalities are power of hybris, other solutions maybe solve same challenge different way.